# MvvmCross - Image failed to download Mvximageview

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am very new to Mvvmcross and Xamarin. So I was making a sample app which is showing a image. Now, I have found few tutorial on how to show image using MvxImageView but the image from the url I want to show is giving me an error. 
Here is the full error stack:

```
07-26 00:35:07.531 D/Mono    (25755): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Core.dll.config'.
07-26 00:35:07.531 D/Mono    (25755): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Core/System.Core.config'.
07-26 00:35:07.531 W/Mono    (25755): The request to load the assembly System.Core v4.0.0.0 was remapped to v2.0.5.0
07-26 00:35:07.531 D/Mono    (25755): Unloading image System.Core.dll [0x96327100].
07-26 00:35:07.536 D/Mono    (25755): Image addref System.Core[0x961f25a0] -> System.Core.dll[0x9b95a000]: 48
07-26 00:35:07.536 D/Mono    (25755): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Core.dll.config'.
07-26 00:35:07.536 D/Mono    (25755): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Core/System.Core.config'.
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755): 169.72 failed to download image https://www.ups.com/rms/image?id=B353E802-8D20-4D4F-B5BA-132D19C9ED24 : WebException: Max. redirections exceeded.
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755):     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755):   at MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.MvxFileDownloadRequest.ProcessResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00017] in D:\git\MvvmCross-Plugins2\DownloadCache\MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache\MvxFileDownloadRequest.cs:55 
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
07-26 00:35:07.936 I/mvx     (25755):   at MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.MvxDynamicImageHelper`1+<RequestImageAsync>d__29[T].MoveNext () [0x001c8] in D:\git\MvvmCross-Plugins2\DownloadCache\MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache\MvxDynamicImageHelper.cs:137 
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:169.72 failed to download image https://www.ups.com/rms/image?id=B353E802-8D20-4D4F-B5BA-132D19C9ED24 : WebException: Max. redirections exceeded.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
at MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.MvxFileDownloadRequest.ProcessResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00017] in D:\git\MvvmCross-Plugins2\DownloadCache\MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache\MvxFileDownloadRequest.cs:55
```

Can someone help me understand why am I getting this error. Thank You!!

Comment: `WebException: Max. redirections exceeded.` Something is redirecting, maybe endlessly, check the source of the image.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I am getting this image from the Api call I make and I also copy pasted image Url into my browser and the image is showing perfectly.